# What is the standard for authorization classes and handlers in ASP dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am researching the proper way to implement authorization in my mvc dotnet core application. [I am following the Microsoft guide on how to do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Seems simple enough, but I have one question that it did not fulfill. Where do those classes sit in? 
For example, I have a solution called Databug. Should I keep the classes (AdmissionsGroup.cs) in the "Databug" solution under the models directory or should I put in the "Infrastructure" directory. Whatever should I do!
[image]

Comment: A folder Infrastructure, inside DataBug seems good to me, you don´t need those classes in a separate assembly as they should be internal to your Web project.

Comment: This is mostly an opinion-based question. I have seen teams do whatever works for them, some store it in Models, some in a separate Authorization folder. Consistency is more important here because going back and forth between ways of doing it will just confuse everybody.